# Как сделать тетраэдр?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь создать CSS-тетраэдр, поэтому я решаю эту проблему, выполнив несколько CSS3-треугольников и активировав трехмерные трансформации с помощью свойства `perspective`.

Но у меня есть некоторые проблемы, чтобы понять все трансформации, вот часть моего кода

```css
.navbar-brand-logo {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.face {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 64px 32px 0 32px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
}
.logo-base-left {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateY(-64px);
}
.logo-base-right {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-64px);
}
.logo-up {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scaleY(0.5) translateY(-64px);
}
.logo-down-up {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
  border-width: 64px 0 0px 4px;
  transform: scaleX(128px) translateZ(0px);
}
```

```html
<section class="navbar-brand-logo">
  <figure class="face logo-base-left"></figure>
  <figure class="face logo-base-right"></figure>
  <figure class="face logo-up"></figure>
  <figure class="face logo-down-up"></figure>
</section>
```

У меня есть проблемы, чтобы представить, как я могу сделать две других грани (слева вверху и справа)

Вот     [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKmJjL)    , который иллюстрирует текущую попытку:

Кроме того, это хорошая идея использовать тетраэдр CSS3 в качестве логотипа? Или бы лучше, если бы это был SVG?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to make a tetrahedron?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33332392/7394871) от участника  [@Raito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3050140/raito).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/33332392/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вот несколько шагов, описывающих подход к созданию адаптивного тетраэдра:     [demo - responsive tetrahedron](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/wGmWOq?editors=1100)    .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Шаг 1. грани

[Тетраэдр](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) имеет 4 треугольных грани. Каждая грань представляет собой [равносторонний треугольник](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle). В следующем примере я использовал свойство [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), чтобы сделать 4 равносторонних треугольника:

```css
.tetra{
  position:relative;
  width:20%; 
  padding-bottom:17.32%; /* height of equilateral triangle = sin60° * width */
  margin:0 auto;
}

.tetra div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background:teal;
}

.tetra .face2{
  transform-origin:0% 100%;
  transform:rotate(-60deg);
  background:gold;
}
.tetra .face3{
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
  transform:rotate(60deg);
  background:darkorange;
}
.tetra .face4{
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="tetra">
  <div class="face1"></div>
  <div class="face2"></div>
  <div class="face3"></div>
  <div class="face4"></div>
</div>
```

### Шаг 2. сделать это 3d

для этого вам нужно повернуть каждую грань отдельно в 3d среде с [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) и в [transform-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style):

```css
body{
  perspective:9000px;
}
.tetra{
  position:relative;
  width:20%; 
  padding-bottom:17.32%; /* height of equilateral triangle = sin60° * width */
  margin:0 auto;  
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.tetra div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background:teal;  
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.tetra .face2{
  transform-origin:0% 100%;
  transform:rotate(-60deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:gold;
}
.tetra .face3{
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
  transform:rotate(60deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:darkorange;
}
.tetra .face4{
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  transform:rotate(180deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="tetra">
  <div class="face1"></div>
  <div class="face2"></div>
  <div class="face3"></div>
  <div class="face4"></div>
</div>
```

На данный момент у вас есть тетраэдр, но вы можете видеть только 3 грани, чтобы увидеть всю трехмерную фигуру:

### Шаг 3. заставить его вращаться!

Сверху вы увидите весь тетраэдр, вам нужно повернуть его с анимацией `transition` или keyframe animation:

```css
body{
  perspective:9000px;
  padding-top:10%;
}
.tetra{
  position:relative;
  width:20%; 
  padding-bottom:17.32%; /* height of equilateral triangle = sin60° * width */
  margin:0 auto;  
  transform-style:preserve-3d;  
  transform:rotatex(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotatez(0deg);
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
}

.tetra div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background:teal;  
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.tetra .face2{
  transform-origin:0% 100%;
  transform:rotate(-60deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:gold;
}
.tetra .face3{
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
  transform:rotate(60deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:darkorange;
}
.tetra .face4{
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  transform:rotate(180deg) rotatex(-109.5deg);
  background:pink;
}
@keyframes rotate{
  50%{transform:rotatex(100deg) rotateY(10deg) rotatez(180deg);}
  100%{transform:rotatex(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotatez(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="tetra">
  <div class="face1"></div>
  <div class="face2"></div>
  <div class="face3"></div>
  <div class="face4"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to make a tetrahedron?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600734/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>